# InflateInputStream.Read() causing ANR in my app. Am trying to decompress a text file from the app. This function works well in Intelij

Tags: java, android

I want to decompress a file from my app using the function below. This function works well from my laptop when i run the code in InteliJ; but causes ANR when I install the app on my device. And fails to decompress the file.
//
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()+"/file1.cmp");

```
    //assign output file: file3 to FileOutputStream for reading the data 

    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir()+"/file3.txt"); 

      

    //assign inflaterInputStream to FileInputStream for uncompressing the data 

    InflaterInputStream iis=new InflaterInputStream(fis); 

      

    //read data from inflaterInputStream and write it into FileOutputStream  

    int data; 
  while((data=iis.read())!=-1) 
    { 
        fos.write(data); 
    } 

      

    //close the files 

    fos.close(); 

    iis.close();
```

Comment: Your `FileOutputStream` is not pointing to a valid location to write to. Also, we do not know where `fis` is coming from. In terms of the ANR, none of this code should be running on the main application thread -- please move it to a background thread.

Comment: fis is the FileInputStream (Compressed file). The file to be decompressed is 1mb and does running this code on the main thread affect it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I now see that line outside of the source-formatted section. That `FileInputStream`, like your `FileOutputStream`, is not pointing to a valid filesystem location.

Comment: That's the actual path to app directory I have updated

Comment: OK! That's better! "does running this code on the main thread affect it?" -- well, it means that your UI is frozen, and if your code takes 5+ seconds, you are going to get this sort of error. If you move your work to a background thread, you will not freeze your UI and you will not get this sort of error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. However, it doesn't decompress the file after all. That's why am stuck